# DI Singleton Service Instantiates Twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I register a service as Singleton in the program.cs file like this.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITest, Test>();
```

and if I request an instance of it in program.cs

```
var testService = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
                                  .GetRequiredService<ITest>();
```

It creates a new object which is the first object, but when I request it through constructor injection in some other service it creates a new object again. Shouldn't it return the first object that it created while startup in Program.cs?

**Note :** This behavior is only if I request service in the program.cs other than that it returns the same object, even if I request it using IServiceProvider.GetRequiredService();

i have tested the same scenario in dot net 5 web api as well in which i register the service in **ConfigureServices method of Startu.cs file**

```
services.AddSingleton<ITest, Test>();
```

and request the service in **Configure method** like this

```
 var test = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ITest>();
```

and when i request it in constructor in some other service it will return the same object.

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your starup file, you don't have a service provider yet. You only have the `Services` property that allows you to *define* your services.

Since you want to instantiate one, you call `builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()` which *builds* a service provider for you, that you then use to get a service. Inside *that* service provider, your service lives as singleton.

Then, you proceed in your application and the framework, being happy that you defined your services, then builds *it's own* service provider. Which you can access via `app.ApplicationServices`. That one, too, has a single instance of your class, since it's a singleton.

And from now on, since all your services and controllers use the service provider created by the framework, not the one you created manually in startup, all of them will get the same instance.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand why it's behaving like this. so now is there any way to get registered service in the startup file, that can be shared inside the application as well?

Comment: Well, you could just create an instance of the singleton and register *that* instance to be your singleton. `var instance = new Test(); builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITest>(instance);` then you can do anything you want with `instance` in your startup and you will get it when you call upon the DI.

Comment: I am in the same situation. But was this behaviour new to .net6 ? I had an application running .net core 2.1 Service Fabric application and it was working fine there. After I upgraded things to .net 6, this behaviour started.